# Range lookup through hierarchical tables in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a very large 2D shape that's divided into smaller 2D shapes, each of which is divided into smaller ones, and so on, for a few levels of hierarchy. Each of these divisions are specified in a pair of numpy 2d arrays with start/end coordinates in each row.

I have to take another list of ranges, and for each find the leaf range they belong to. I can manually traverse through the hierarchy one by one, but I'm doing this for thousands of ranges and I'm looking for a way to vectorize it through numpy.

I can assume that each range will hit exactly one table row, so I can easily look up the ranges on the first level:

```
np.argwhere(
   ((start >= table_start) & (end <= table_end)).all(axis=-1)
)[:,1]
```

Now I'm not sure how to efficiently repeat this for the second-level tables. I can do something like `np.take` to extract hits for each of the sub-tables, and then repeat the lookup in those tables, and so on and so on... however, I'm then starting to do a lot of python `for` loops to go table by table, and I'm also losing the original order of the start/end pairs so I'll have to keep track of their mapping on the side... and it all seems to become more complicated than it should be.

It feels like there should be some kind of "numpy way" of mapping results from one lookup to where the next lookup should happen... but I haven't been able to find one.

Here's a toy example:

```
  import numpy as np

  start = np.array([[0, 0], [2, 2], [4, 2]])
  end = np.array([[1, 1], [3, 3], [4, 3]])
  start = np.expand_dims(start, axis=-2)
  end = np.expand_dims(end, axis=-2)

  top_table_start = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 2], [0, 4]])
  top_table_end = np.array([[4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 6]])

  indices = np.argwhere(
      ((start >= top_table_start) & (end <= top_table_end)).all(axis=-1)
  )[:, 1]
  print(indices)
  # [0, 1, 1]
  # first range is in table 0, the next two are in table 1

  subtable_start = [[] for _ in range(2)]
  subtable_end = [[] for _ in range(2)]
  subtable_start[0] = np.array([[0, 0], [2, 0]])
  subtable_end[0] = np.array([[2, 0], [4, 0]])
  subtable_start[1] = np.array([[0, 2], [2, 2]])
  subtable_end[1] = np.array([[2, 2], [4, 2]])

  # Now need to lookup first start/end pair in subtable0, and the other two in subtable1...?!
  # ...
```

I have considered flattening the structure so that all the leaf ranges are in one table... however, then we're looking at a gigantic table lookup, and it's not going to be faster than manual hierarchical traversal.

Comment: Off hand this sounds like a poor fit for `numpy`.  Unless you can somehow cast is a multidimensional array, e.g shape (2,2,2,2,2) etc.

Comment: You might be right... I'm not married to it, but I also haven't been able to find any other libraries that would work better. And it seemed like too simple of a thing to have to implement by hand in C to get the speed. I'm hoping somebody has a creative way to approach it.

Comment: Here is one way that you can try to break down the problem. Let's say that in a pre-processing step you can get an array `arr` where `arr[i] = [l1, l2, l3, ..., ln]` where `lk` denotes the starting index of the leaf range for the `k`'th leaf. Then, you could find the appropriate leaf range for each row with `np.searchsorted`.

Comment: Creating the list of *all* the leafs is going to be huge... but I like the `searchsorted` idea, I'm going to experiment with that - thanks!